# Si quiero mantener un juicio neutro, ¿debo usar "los que somos hábiles" o "los que son hábiles"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, estilo, educación

Esta duda surge de la conjugación diferente de la primera y tercera personas del plural en español, la cual no está presente algunos idiomas.

Supóngase que estoy hablando con una persona de confianza y le digo

> – Los que somos hábiles para  ...

Entonces se entiende que yo me considero *hábil*. A veces, sin embargo, es deseable hablar de cierto grupo de gente sin hacerle saber al interlocutor si me estoy incluyendo en tal grupo o no; emitir un juicio neutro, independiente de la percepción que uno tenga de sí mismo. Sin embargo, si la tercera persona es usada, cierta gente tiende a percibir la afirmación como si el hablante se estuviera no sólo excluyendo del grupo, sino autocalificándose de lo contrario.

**Ejemplo:** Si uno dice

> – Los que son hábiles para cocinar...

ciertos interlocutores tienen la impresión de que uno se está considerando 
inhábil para cocinar.

- ¿Es algo inherente al idioma español o es un problema cultural?
- Naturalmente hay una solución neutra para expresar eso. ¿Cómo evitar tal problema sin necesidad de formular frases complejas?

Answer (score 7):

Quizá una solución elegante sea usar la segunda persona del singular:

> Si eres hábil para cocinar puedes trabajar en cualquier restaurante.

De esta manera implicamos directamente a nuestro interlocutor u oyente, del cual se supone no conocemos sus habilidades culinarias. Así el interlocutor (sepa de cocina o no) separa inconscientemente su "yo" de "los demás", destacando como hábiles sólo aquellos que él considere como tal (de la misma forma que también se considera a sí mismo hábil o no).

Esto si bien no es neutro como tal,es una manera de forzar un jucio neutro al traspasar la responsabilidad de clasificar al interlocutor.

---

Otra manera es usar directamente la forma neutra, tal como sugieres, que se me ocurre podría ser:

> Si se es hábil para cocinar se puede trabajar en cualquier restaurante.

O bien...

> Si alguien es hábil cocinando puede trabajar en cualquier restaurante.

En cualquiera de estos dos casos estamos usando una forma condicional para expresarlo, de tal manera que no queda implícito ningún sujeto específico en la frase. Estamos hablando simplemente de supuestos.

---

Sobre si es inherente al español o no, eso ya escapa de mi conocimiento, pero quizá otro usuario pueda aportar más luz al asunto.